# Intellij idea showing incorrect warning

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, annotations

I am using the following version of Intellij Idea

[image]

When I try to @Autowire in spring like

```
@Autowired private DBManager dbManager;
```

Ith shows the warning: **Private field 'dbManager' is never assigned**

How I can suppress such kind of warnings which is not relevant.

Comment: By not using the community edition.

Comment: By ading a `@SuppressWarning` or modifying the comportment of the parser.

Comment: @Nathan Yes, that will work but I have to write **SuppressWarning** at all **Autowired** in my source code.

Comment: I haven't used Autowired specifically, but with other annotations, the actions it suggests for the warning include "ignore this warning for any field annotated with this annotation." Do you have that? (I have community edition, too)

Comment: Same happens for `@Inject` which is *not* a Spring feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integration with Spring and other frameworks available in Intellij IDEA Ultimate, but you're using Community Edition version which supports mainly Java Core features so there's no inspection capable of determining whether or not the field is assigned.

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions of CE you can suppress these when @Autowired annotation is present, by using the light bulb (I'm using version 2022.2)